# Array.map returns ArraySeq

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have written the following function to transform an RDD

```
def project[T](rdd: RDD[Array[T]], cols: Array[Int]): RDD[Array[T]] = {
  return rdd.map(allCols => { cols.map(allCols(_)) })
}
```

however when I try and compile this this I get

```
[INFO]  found   : scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[T]
[INFO]  required: Array[T]
[INFO]  return rdd.map(allCols => { cols.map(allCols(_)) })
```

My interpretation of this is that Scala is inferring the type of the map to be ArraySeq, however I am not sure why this is the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I compiles fine in Scala 2.11 `def project[T](rdd: RDD[Array[T]], cols: Array[Int]): RDD[Array[T]] = rdd.map(allCols => cols.map(allCols))`

Comment: Looks like your map function changes the type of the array from T to Seq[T]. So either fix that or change the return type of the transformation.